# Wordpress search plugin

Tags: wordpress, search, plugins, content-management-system

Is there any word-press plug-in that shows multiple filtering searching option. Or any plug-in that shows search like this as on page given.Here is link http://sydney.edu.au/courses/ or near to this search.

Comment: you can crate it yourself.
what you expected to list inside that dropdown ? post type or category ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this plug-in will do exactly what you need

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-by-category/screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

For post type wise search

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="Enter keywords ..." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/><br />
    <select name="post_type">
        <option value="">Choose Post types</option>
        <option value="">All Post types</option>
        <option value="post_type_a">Post Type A</option>
        <option value="post_type_b">Post Type B</option>
         <option value="post_type_c">Post Type C</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search Help" />
</form>
```

for Category wise search use this

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
        <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="Enter keywords ..." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/><br />
        <select name="cat">
            <option value="">Choose Category</option>
            <option value="">All Categories</option>
            <option value="categoryID">Category01</option>
            <option value="categoryID">Category01</option>
             <option value="categoryID">Category01</option>
        </select><br />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search Help" />
    </form>
```